# calling a css3 transition from jquery

Tags: jquery, css

CSS3 transitions are great! So far, I'm triggering them with :hover or :active declarations in the stylesheet. I'm looking to see if there's a way to trigger them from jquery.

For instance:

```
#MyDiv{
border:1px solid red;
background:blue;
transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

MyDiv:hover{
border:1px solid black;
background:yellow;
}
```

The :hover transition will trigger when the mouse moves over MyDiv but what I'm looking to do is something like:

```
$('#MyDiv').transition(hover); //that would be ideal
```

In other words, I'd like to trigger the css animation so that if I mouseover some other div, the #MyDiv animation will trigger with `$('#SomeOtherDiv').mouseenter(function () { $('#MyDiv').transition(hover); });`

The jquery animate function doesn't support color transitions and while I know you can add jqueryUI plugins to make it work, I was wondering if there's some way to make it work without, using jquery to call the css transition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#MyDiv {
    border:1px solid red;
    background:blue;
    transition: all 2.0s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.hover{
    border:1px solid black;
    background:yellow;
    transition: all 2.0s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

$("#MyOtherDiv")
.mouseenter(function(){
    $("#MyDiv").addClass("hover");
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    $("#MyDiv").removeClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed your example and got it to work: you need to remove the border and background definition from #MyDiv and put them in a different class called Regular, so that you have <div id="MyDiv" class="Regular"> see fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/v7AA7/11/

Comment: The reason is that a id selector weights heavier than a simple class selector, so, change the .hover to #MyDiv.hover and it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/v7AA7/191/

Answer (score 3):

For better mobile device performance, I would use **webkit-transform** rather than webkit-transition since you are going to be getting the hardware acceleration benefits from the mobile device, resulting in a smoother, native look when performing these transitions using CSS3.

In fact, I'd go ahead and get the [jQuery Transit plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), which makes it easy to use jQuery to invoke a given transition. It basically takes care of the CSS3 transitions for you and gives cross-browser compatibility.

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DLPd2/2/)

**Javascript:**

```
$("#startTransition").on("click", function()
{
    $("#MyDiv").transition({ background: 'yellow', color: 'black'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any jQuery for this purpose.
http://jsfiddle.net/v7AA7/ — example

```
#MyDiv{
    border:1px solid red;
    background:blue;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

#MyDiv:hover{
    border:1px solid black;
    background:yellow;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

Comment: No, I meant I want to trigger the transition on MyDiv when I'm hovering on SomeOtherDiv.

Answer (score 0):

```
#MyDiv {
    border:1px solid red;
    background:blue;
    transition: all 2.0s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

#MyDiv.hover{
    border:1px solid black;
    background:yellow;
    transition: all 2.0s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

$("#MyOtherDiv")
.mouseenter(function(){
    $("#MyDiv").addClass("hover");
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    $("#MyDiv").removeClass("hover");
});
```

Fixed Scott's answer.  His wasn't working because the #MyDiv styles were overriding the .hover styles because its more specific.  I changed the .hover style to include the id, which then allows it to override the #MyDiv style.